# I want my code to print only if the result is different from previous result and not the same thing again

Tags: python, api, logging, blockchain, solidity

This code prints the most recent result that it fetches from api_url whenever I run the code, but I want it to check if result is same as last then do not print it.

Note: This is my first time asking a question here so please forgive, If I made any mistake in the question.

```
 api_url= "https://api.bscscan.com/api? module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=smartcontract&address=" + person1["address"] + \
    "&startblock=10290674&endblock=999999999&page=1&offset=1&sort=desc&apikey=APIKEY"

 response = requests.get(api_url)
 address_content = response.json()
 result = address_content.get("result")  

 for n, transaction in enumerate(result):
    block = transaction.get("blockNumber")
    hash = transaction.get("hash")
    tx_from = transaction.get("from")
    tx_to = transaction.get("to")
    value = transaction.get("value")
    confirmations = transaction.get("confirmations")

    coin_value = Decimal(value)/1000000000000000000

    coin_value = int(value)/1000000000
    print("COIN", coin_value)
    print("\n")
    
    if tx_to in (tx_sell, tx_sell2):
        print("sell")
    elif tx_from in (tx_sell, tx_sell2):
        print("buy")
```

Comment: Persist the last result somehow (pickle, file, xml, ...) load it on scripstart, compare it against your current vaule. Tons of questions about storing of information here - search python + pickle. To print or not to print, is no longer a question if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

store the result in a filelike:

```
myfile = open(“result.txt”,’w’)

myfile.write(str(result))
```